# Block all but one ip address

Tags: security, iptables

I need to allow access to only one IP address and block the rest, so I wrote the following:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s ipaddress -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

But I still cannot ping that ipaddress? what is wrong with the above statements?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt to ping "ipaddress" doesn't get out in the first place, as it gets dropped in the output chain. Try this:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s ipaddress -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d ipaddress -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

Note that you may or may not need to allow some other minimal traffic for your system to actually work properly. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634788/iptables-allow-just-internet-connection) other answer.

Comment: You forgot to allow localhost via loopback - not allowing that could cause some hell with the system communicating with itself (so I added it back in)

Comment: @ThomasW. That depends on what the user is doing with his computer, and is covered in the link I gave, But yes, O.K., I certainly have it it any minimal testing I do. Thanks.

Comment: True, however if they want to communicate with only one IP address outside their computer, then local loopback should still operate.  Ideally, you wouldn't block localhost from communicating with itself.  (The rest of the logic is valid though)

Comment: @ThomasW. Agreed. Now, and just out of curiosity, I removed the lo ACCEPT line, from my iptables script from the other [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/634788/iptables-allow-just-internet-connection), and it is working fine. It is a minimal test server though.

Comment: We need more info form the OP.  If they are using the Graphical Ubuntu, and the IP they are communicating with has DNS resolution somewhere, then it needs to have access locally for resolution (i.e. having lo access).  However, we are missing a LOT of use case information from the OP to adequately decide whether to keep `lo` access or not.

Comment: Thank you Doug and Thomas very much. Once I allowed OUTPUT to the IP, I could ping successfully. This was just a test, so I used a test IP such as 8.8.8.8 and 4.2.2.2. But the actual case would be using a small java socket application to communicate with a specific IP address (x.x.x.x, not name) through sending and receiving byte streams. I didn't need to allow localhost. Also, only the Graphical Ubuntu and this java application are running on the computer, nothing else. Very simple. So, I needed simple protection to guarantee that no other IP can communicate with the computer.